# UITableView frame postion incorrect when view loads

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController`, one level deep inside a `UINavigationController`. The `rootviewController` is a slide out menu - library over here: https://github.com/mobivery/MVYSideMenu

**The problem**

When the `UiTableViewController` loads - its in the incorrect position and after half a second, it moves down to the correct position by it self. Looks really odd.

So, as a test, I created a new `UIViewController` with only boiler plate code and put it one level deep in the `UiNavigationController`. I then added a `UIbutton` to it and when the view loads, the button is always in the correct position.

So, I then added a `UITableView` to this `UIViewController` and positioned it half way down the screen. I also manually added auto layout constraints to it.

Now, re running the test - the exact same thing happens - the `UITableView` starts out just above its original position, and half a second later, it moves down to its correct position.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and what could cause it?

Thanks!

Comment: How many pixels is the offset ? Do you change the navigation bar translucency ?

Comment: By offset, do you mean how much does it move by? If, so, then I'd say it moves at least 50 points down from its starting position. I haven't changed the navigation bat translucency. The new UIViewController I tested with was untouched code wise except for the tableview boilerplate code implementation.

Comment: Yes that what i meant, could it be the navigationbar's height ?

Comment: Now that you meant ion it, yes. The height of the navigation bar is the same offset the UITableView moves down by.

Comment: I believe something changes between initialization and when view appears. Could you post a little more code such as viewDidLoad ? Do you use interface builder btw ?

Comment: I think you're on the right track here. I don't have any code at all in viewWillLoad or viewDidLoad in the UiNavigation controller or its childViewControllers as I have removed it to test. However, its stll happening. I believe there may be an issue in the side menu controller code that I use to bring the menu out - just quickly going through it and will report back. How do I track what code is executed, without putting breakpoints everywhere?

Comment: @Justafinger So I tested the slide out menu library in a fresh project, with the same view setup as my main project. It works fine there. So the error is not in the slide out menu. It must be somewhere else. Where else do you think I could look if my viewDidLoad and viewWillApear methods don't have code?

Comment: Maybe in your xib or storyboard, check the property of your navigation bar, try changing the translucency. I know that this behavior happens when you set a translucency in a IB and another in the code. Try seeking navigationBar.translucent in your project.

Comment: @Justafinger Problem found! - the issue is "Under Top Bars" setting, for "Extend Edges" for the viewControllers that had the issue. Not sure why it causes the view to move down, but it solved the issue. Thanks dude, you rock! - Add your comment as an answer and I'll happily accept. Do you know why this causes an issue, by the way?

Comment: Well, i'm glad i could help, however i don't know this settings (i believe because i don't use storyboard) I'll let you post your own answer if you want, with maybe a little more details.